# Poor FPS and IO when cold booted but OK when warm

Tags: ssd, performance, gpu

I have a bizarre issue with a system where the system performs poorly when cold booted. Video is under 60fps in games and 1/3rd the IO performance of the SSD as reported by CrystalDiskMark. When warm booted (quick restart) everything is OK.

The system specs are:

```
Ryzen 5 CPU
ASRock MB AB350M Pro4
MSI GeForce 1060 GTX 6GB
Crucial 2x8GB 3200Mhz ram
Samsung 960 Pro M.2
```

OS is Windows 10 and we've loaded the latest bios and drivers for every thing. We've also tried turning off Fast Boot in Windows as recommended on some forums. We've also found reports of very similar behavior due to G-sync but this function isn't available on the nvidia panel for this card.

Comment: Very odd... Are you able to borrow another more powerful PSU to test?

Comment: @Dave thanks. We tried as you suggested but there was no difference.

Comment: I assume that the borrowed PSU was more powerful? 
I think this is too broad simply because unless some one has actually experienced this, sadly, it's going to be trial and error. Remove everything you can to have a bare-bones machine. Does the same issue occur? If not, then hopefully this means you can start adding components one at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: Yes it was more powerful. Trial and error it is... :(